# How can I Iterate an array of numbers and escape printing a number out of the array and print a text instead of that escaped number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, break

I want to iterate and print this array in console but once the number 4 came it should escape printing four and it should print I'm at four and then print the rest of the numbers?

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);
  if (array[i] === 4) {
    console.log("I'm at four")
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Think about the order in which the code is executed, your condition is *after* the value has already been logged. Use in `if...else` if it helps you conceptualize it. `if (array[i] === 4) { console.log("I'm at four");} else {console.log(array[i]);}`. This also avoids the need for `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the output at the end of the loop.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 4) {
        console.log("I'm at four");
        continue;
    }
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```